# Marking the legend in center for bubble chart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm playing around this highchart:

https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/packed-bubble-split

Packed bubble split, I wanted to make the legends (`Asia`, `Europe` etc) to appear in the center of each bubble. Is it possible with `events`?
I tried something like this:

```
Highcharts.chart(chartContainer, {
    chart: {
        type: 'packedbubble',
        renderTo: chartContainer,
        events: {
            render: function() {
                const chart = this;
                chart.series.forEach(function (series) {
                    var data = series.data; // Get all the data points for the series
                    var totalX = 0;
                    var totalY = 0;
                    var totalPoints = data.length;

                    // Calculate the total X and Y coordinates of the data points
                   
                        })
                        .add();
                });
            }
        }
    },
```

No luck, I can't place them in center. Wondering if there is a way I achieve it?

Comment: Please add the dysfunctional code to the jsfiddle so we can take a look at what the issue is. Also try to show the desired output against the current output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the below plugin which will add the required custom label and position it during animation.

```
(function(H) {
    . . . .
    series.customLabel.attr({
      x: series.parentNode.plotX + chart.plotLeft,
      y: series.parentNode.plotY + chart.plotTop - 10
    });
  });
}(Highcharts));
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/v1ew6bLc/

**Docs:** https://www.highcharts.com/docs/extending-highcharts/extending-highcharts

Comment: Looks like its affecting all charts, is there a way I can attach this to only packedBubble?

Comment: Hi @Ant's, Sure, you can for example check for `chart.type`. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/gemyqnz8/

Comment: Thanks much. Last question, is it possible to have a background color for the text?

Comment: Yes, just use the `fill` attribute. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/bn9oy4Lq/